# Plot.ly js wind rose chart

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly

can someone help me how to generate different color in one wind rose area of plotly js?
I am having hard time on solving different colors in one area because all I know is in every area of wind rose, it should have 1 color each area.
Below is the image on what I am trying to inform to all of you.

Wind rose chart
[image]

and also, how can I overlap the lines/radius lines so that the color on every area in visible rather than the lines. And how can I remove those label axis names. In the right section, I just manually put the color but the color should be the same from the chart but dynamic colors.
Thanks for the help